# Assembly 8086, is there way to store half of bytes from each line from input, and then print first half of those lines?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I am new to assembly programming and I am stuck for quite a while on this problem. My program should take lines from input, and print the first half of bytes of the first half of lines as return.

When I try to run my code with the following input:

```
first line
second line
third line
fourth line
```

I recieve this:

d

firs

While this is something I should get:

first (10 // 2)

secon   (11 // 2)

I though that I could read all the lines one by one, shorten it, and save along with its final length. Then just read it from the place where I stored it and print first half of them using cnt_lns as counter later.

Here is what I have:

```
cpu 8086
segment extra
buffer resb 60000

segment code
..start mov bx, data
        mov ds, bx
        mov bx, stack
        mov ss, bx
        mov sp, dno
    mov bx, extra
    mov es, bx


read_lines:
        mov ah, 0x0a
        mov dx, read
        int 21h
        jz print_lines

        mov cx, [cnt_lns]
        inc cx
        mov [cnt_lns], cx

    
    
shorten_lines:
        mov bx, 0
        mov bl, byte [read + 1]
    mov bh, 0
        shr bx, 1
    
    mov [line + bx], byte 13
    mov [line + bx + 1], byte 10
    inc bx

    mov [line_ln], bx
    mov cx, bx
    
    mov bx, buffer
    add bx, [total_len]
    mov si, line
    mov di, bx
    rep movsb
    
    mov bx, [line_ln]
    add [total_len], bx
    
print_lines:
    mov cx, [total_len]
    mov bx, 0
cycle:
    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, [buffer + bx]
    int 21h
    inc bx
    dec cx
    jnz cycle
    
done: hlt

segment data
read        db  100, ?
line        resb 100

line_ln     db    0

cnt_lns     dw    0
total_len   dw    0


segment stack
        resb 16
dno:    db ?
```

I would be very grateful for any help or explanation. Thanks everyone! <3

Comment: Flags returned from DOS service [Int 21/AH=0Ah](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm) are not documented, so it is unclear if `jz print_lines`  jumps or not.

Comment: Debug it to find out why it doesn't print an `f` as the first thing.  Start debugging by working with the smallest possible input.

Comment: Yes, reading one character at a time, you can rewind to the middle of a line each time you see a newline (or CRLF), overwrite with a CRLF, and start reading the next line at that position in the buffer.  That sounds like a working algorithm if you do it right.  Trickier to do with DOS `int 21h` / `AH=0Ah` since it needs 2 bytes of lengths before the actual data it reads, but I guess you already need a CRLF between two eventual-output lines anyway so those bytes can overlap that and be replaced after reading the length.  You don't actually need to save any old data in registers to make room.

Comment: I see your code is using `rep movsb` to copy something, though; that's unnecessary if you read into place in your large buffer.  http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a.  But it might be simpler, at least to debug, to read into a separate buffer, if you find that easier to think about.

Comment: DO NOT deface your question by deleting content after you receive an answer. Under the [Terms of Service - Subscriber Content](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public) you agree that any and all content, ... you provide ... is ... licensed to Stack Overflow ... pursuant to Creative Commons licensing terms (CC-BY-SA), and you grant Stack Overflow the ... right ... to ... display ... such [content], even if such [content] has been ... removed by you.

Answer (score 2):

### You can't run this NASM code on emu8086!

In emu8086, an instruction like `mov dx, read` will not load the address of the input structure in DX, but rather load a word from memory. So not what you need. This boils down to DOS performing an input and storing the result somewhere else than what you expect.

The DOS.BufferedInput function 0Ah does not return any flags. Therefore acting on the zero flag (`jz print_lines`) will produce unexpected results.

In *shorten_lines* where you add carriage return and linefeed bytes, you only add 1 to BX. That's not enough as you will loose the linefeed byte again.

With just 16 bytes, your stack is way too small to function correctly. A normal size would be 256 bytes, but don't be afraid to make it even bigger like say 1024.

### Solution

I would not have chosen to use the DOS.BufferedInput function 0Ah to solve this task. Even if you loose its (limited) editing capabilities, the [method described by Peter Cordes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74879519/assembly-8086-is-there-way-to-store-half-of-bytes-from-each-line-from-input-an#comment132151948_74879519) is much easier to understand and implement. If you show an interest, I just might program it... Seems fun enough.